# Differentiating missing documents in MongoDB find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I run the following query I am getting the document that matches as normal which is "LON" in this case.

But is there any way that I can make the response seperately return the values that didn't match or found, which is "BUJ" in this case. Instead of running a for loop for individual values.

```
ports = [
    "LON",
    "BUJ"
];

findDatas = async(coll, values, key) => {
    let datas = await coll.find({[key] : values});
    // let datas = await coll.find().where(key).in(values);
    console.log(datas)
}

findDatas(airportsModel, ports, "iata_code")
```

In my DB I only have "LON" which mean "BUJ" is not found. So is there any way to make mongo to tell that the given values haven't been found? along with the found ones.

Comment: Can you try to explain what exactly are you trying to achieve because your current explanation is not clear enough. You want to find all ports which are not equal to `"LON" ` or you want to search for a list of ports `["LON", "BUJ"]` with one query?

Comment: In my DB I only have "LON" which mean "BUJ" is not found. So is there any way to make mongo to tell that the given values haven't been found? along with the found ones.

Comment: Why do you need this information? I don't think there is such option available - this is not how most databases operate. I guess you have to do it with a for-each and dispatch a query for individual values.

Comment: So you need it to both return all of the documents that match, and count the number that matched each element of the query?

Comment: I have done the for loop method but it like a lot queries for a big search. And getting all the datas and processing all of them for a small is also is a bit of large process for the server that's why I was wondering weather is there any solution. @ Tsvetan Ganev

Comment: Sort of or separately return the matched and not matched ones. But the goal is to make it in a single query. @Joe

Answer (score 0):

This code dynamically creates a `$match` stage to find the documents, the uses `$facet` to split into 2 pipelines, the first returns the documents, the second uses a `$group` stage created from the input array to count how many documents match each element.  The result should be a document with 2 fields: `documents` and `counts`

```
matchdata={};
matchdata[key]={"$in":ports};
groupdata = {_id:null};
ports.forEach(function(p){
        groupdata[p] = {"$sum":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$" + key, p ]},1,0]}}
});
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$match:matchdata},
  {$facet:{
     documents:[{$match:{}}],
     counts:[{$group: groupdata},{$project:{_id:0}}]
  }}
])
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the counting part.

Comment: That will be really hard to find without sample data